# CreateModelMixin does not insert one of the fields passed in the request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mixins

I'm building a Django web app and I use the `CreateModelMixin` in a `CRUDGeneric` class to abstract the CRUD operations. However, I've got a problem where one of the fields (the password) of POST /user request is not being saved into the database. I've checked the request up until the call for the `create` method and the request is correct.

```
print request.data
response = super(CRUDGeneric, self).create(request, args, kwargs)
```

The output of `request.data`:

```
{u'last_name': u'Last', u'first_name': u'First', u'vvuser': {u'mobile': u'1234', u'bio': u''}, u'is_active': True, u'password': u'password', u'email': u'email@email.com'}
```

I've checked the implementation of `CreateModelMixin.create` and don't see how it could be failing to insert the password field?:

```
class CreateModelMixin(object):
    """
    Create a model instance.
    """
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def get_success_headers(self, data):
        try:
            return {'Location': data[api_settings.URL_FIELD_NAME]}
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            return {}
```

Anyone got any ideas? Maybe I'm looking at the wrong place, but this seems to be the place where the object is being saved into the DB.

Comment: Are you creating a django `User` object with this view?

Comment: What does your serializer look like?

Comment: @tredzko yes I'm creating a django `User`. I've just got transfered to this project recently. There are two different tables for Users... One which `auth_user` (I think this is the standard Django User table?) and another one which has a reference to the first table (this table is meant to provide further details on users).

Comment: @slider I don't have my own serializer. The serializer I showed in the second code snippet I posted belongs to the Django REST Framework which I don't have access to.